# Finding Max, Min, Avg using dynamic memory allocation and pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

I am learning pointers so I tried to implement this simple code of finding Max, min and Avg of student grades.
I only could found the *avg* **BUT** for the *Max* and the *Min* I got the first element of the `*p`.

here is my code **If you please can tell me what is my mistake**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int *p;
    int x;

cout << "Enter a number of student: ";
cin >> x;
p = new int[x];

for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
{
    cout << "Enter a grade: ";
    cin >> *(p + i);
}
int sum = 0;
int max = 0;
int min = 0;
max = *p;
min = *p;

for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
{
    if (min > *p)
    {
        min = *p;
        p++;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
{
    if (max < *p)
    {
        max = *p;
        p++;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
{
    sum += *p;
    p++;
}
int avg = sum / x;
cout << "avg is : " << avg << endl;
cout << "Max num is : "<< max 
     << "\n Min num is : " << min << endl;
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the changes

```
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        if (min > *(p+i))
        {
            min = *(p+i);//changed

        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        if (max < *(p+i))
        {
            max = *(p+i);//changed

        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        sum += *(p+i);//changed

    }
```

Comment: Now you are cool .. I check for you as the right answer :)
and btw I dont need to change anything for the sum cuz it works fine like I mentioned before .. thanks again ;)

Answer (score 2):

You only advance the pointer, if `*p` is greater than the current `max` or `min`. Either advance it on every iteration (and back up the original state) or use `p[i]` to get the element of the iteration.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is wrong on a number of levels. First of all, have a look at how you initialize the pointer `p`, which is supposed to point to the beginning of your array containing `int` elements :

```
p = new int[x];
```

This is all good. However, if you now take a look at the first loop...

```
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
{
    if (min > *p)
    {
        min = *p;
        p++;
    }
}
```

You will notice that you keep incrementing `p`, which was supposed to point to the **beginning** of the array. This way, you can't possibly visit every element of the array when you run the second loop, because `p` does not point at the start of your array anymore! Thus, you invoked what some people call *undefined behaviour* by accessing an array out of its bounds.

However, you were able to properly reference the array in the loop where you actually write the elements to it - with the line `cin >> *(p + i);`.

Also, you should always remember to `delete` everything you `new`ed. However, if you lose the pointer to what `new` returned, you will never be able to successfully `delete` it.

Furthermore, if you're programming in C++, you really should avoid using raw pointers, and - if you really need to - wrap them inside an `unique_ptr` (if you're using C++11). When it comes to "dynamic arrays", `std::vector` is most often the better way.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your time and effort .. I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're doing `p++`, thus "losing the pointer".

In each `for` loop except for the first one, change `*p` to `p[i]`, and get rid of the `p++`.

Also, at the end of the function, call `delete p`.

Comment: That worked just fine thanks but why it was working with the avg??

Comment: Just a matter of coincidence. Depending on your input values, you have incremented `p` a few times during the search for `min` and a few times during the search for `max`, and then calculated `avg` over `x` items, meaning that you read a few "junk" values. The only input for which this code will run safely is where all values are the same, because you will not do `p++` inside loop #2 and loop #3.

Answer (score 0):

You could inline the calculation of max, min, and sum:

```
int sum = 0;
int max = 0;
int min = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
{
    int g=0;
    cout << "Enter a grade: ";
    cin >> g;
    if (g > max)
        max = g;
    if (g < min)
        min = g;
    sum += g;
}
```

Then you wouldn't need p = new int[x]